# What does `aws configure` actually do?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

It's important to understand from a security standpoint what `aws configure` actually does behind the scenes. Having read the [docs](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/configure/index.html), I'm still not clear on this.

We have chosen to move the credentials file to a more secure location on our server, i.e. not in the default `%USERPROFILE%\.aws\credentials` location. I set the environment variable, `AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE`, for this secure location and run `aws configure`. Everything seems to work and I am able to use the AWS cli with the access keys provided.

Unfortunately however, I can't be clear on whether `aws configure` has compromised the security of the credentials in some way. For example, by simply moving the file to a non-secure location...

Comment: Install `auditd`, set it up to monitor file system calls and run `aws` then open logs and investigate

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @RomeoNinov. I think it's a good idea. I'm actually trying a similar thing with `strace`, the output of which is ~13k lines. I'm not sure it's really the answer though as I can observe I/O operations but without knowing the implementation I don't really know what's going on, e.g. what is the contents of files being written... Perhaps auditd will be a bit clearer.

Comment: Also, I should say that this is for a windows application so neither `auditd` or `strace` will necessarily help with what's going on in windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aws configure` actually isn't required when using non-default locations for credentials and configurations files. If the file locations for these files are set correctly in the environment variables, `AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE` and `AWS_CONFIG_FILE` respectively, then the aws cli knows where to look for the credentials and configuration. I therefore do not need to worry about any security issues relating to `aws configure`.

Answer (score 0):

"aws configure" simple creates the credential file for you on your workstation or server in the file `%USERPROFILE%\.aws\credentials`. You type the credentials in, it puts them into the file on the local server. As far as I know it doesn't do anything else with the credentials.

You can edit it directly to do exactly the same thing. It's a regular file, holding AWS access key and secret keys.

In terms of security, having your credentials stored in a file on a workstation / server unencrypted isn't ideal. If your computer gets a virus or ransomware they could be lost or stolen. If this ever happens you should remove those keys in the AWS console and issue new keys once your machine is sufficiently secure again.

IMHO the risk is worthwhile if you need to use the AWS CLI, so long as your machine has good security practices. Basics like a firewall, virus / malware scanner, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not 100% sure this is correct however. What I'm talking about is keeping the credentials file in a non-default location and setting that location as the environment variable `AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE` then running `aws configure`, this pattern is explained (here)[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html]. I do agree that the docs would suggest `aws configure` creates the file at `%USERPROFILE%\.aws\credentials`, but having run the pattern above and checked, I can confirm there is no `%USERPROFILE%\.aws\` folder created.

Comment: Behaviour of this command is confusing. I tested by writing the credentials and config files to %USERPROFILE%\.aws\ : I am able to use the keys without needing to run `aws configure`, confirming what you suggest. I have also tested by running `aws configure` and entering the details on prompt. This creates credentials files at the default location. Again, confirming what you suggest. However, when using environment variables to outline non default locations for the files, and then running `aws configure`, `%USERPROFILE%\.aws` is not created, despite the CLI picking up the details correctly.

Comment: Ah. I will edit your question slightly to make it more clear what you're asking.

Comment: The AWS CLI is just reading the contents of the file. I suspect you're over thinking this.

Comment: Thanks Tim. But `aws configure` must be doing something: using cli doesn't work without first running `aws configure` (when putting credentials file in a non-default location). You say "the AWS CLI is just reading the contents of the file", but if this were the case, then it should be able to simply read the environment variables at the point of calling, for example `aws s3 ls`, i.e. it should work without first running `aws configure`. Do you see what I mean? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Thanks for your help @Tim. Think I got to the bottom of this one, prompted by your help. See my answer above.